# CORS requests with session/cookie

Tags: php, session, cookies, cors

My application has a PHP server and a client (a JS single-page app). They are separate projects and deployed in different domains. The client consumes a RESTful API exposed by the server.

This application is to be integrated with a third party which handles authentication, so users cannot login directly. Our server just receives an SSO token (which comes appropriately signed so that we verify its integrity).

We also enforce security at the transport layer for all requests.

What I'd like to do is, once the SSO token is verified, start a session of my own and then redirect the user to the client. I thought that once the session was created the browser would automatically send the right Cookie header in the asynchronous API calls, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Is this deliberately disabled due to security reasons?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must set [`withCredentials`](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-withcredentials-attribute) to `true` for cross-origin XHR requests to include cookies.

The CORS response must also say `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` (which is why `widthCredentials` defaults to `false`).

Comment: Thank you so much. This works. I'm accepting this answer rather than @CBroe 's since this one also mentions the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header.

As a side note, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` cannot be a wildcard (`*`).

Answer (score 2):

> I thought that once the session was created the browser would automatically send the right Cookie header in the asynchronous API calls

Not for cross-domain requests for CORS-enabled ressources (which seems to be the case here, if I understand your described setup correctly.)

To make that happen, you need to set the [`withCredentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) flag.